# Выбор языка программирования для изучения

Tags: работа

Друзья, не посоветуете ли по такому вопросу.

Хотел бы изучить современный язык программирования. Я когда-то программировал на Си (без плюсов), на xBase  и других языках, но это было давно, они устарели.

Интересует вопрос выбора перспективного языка, который позволит как можно раньше начать реальную работу. У нас в провинции программистских контор мало. Остается, я так понимаю, либо работа на удаленного заказчика, либо разработка собственных программ.

Насколько я понимаю, выбор примерно из этого:

C++ (в том числе с Qt для кроссплатформенности) 
 C# (в том числе с MonoTouch/Unity для кроссплатформенности)
 Java 
 JavaScript/HTML/CSS/PHP 
 Android (Java) 
 Objective-C (iOS) 
 Ruby (on Rails) 
 Python 
 Flash/HTML5

Какие тут есть соображения? Спасибо!!

Answer (score 5):

Разрабатывать собственные программы, не имея реального опыта за плечами - я бы не стал так рисковать. Если хотите быстро начать работать и получить реальный опыт, то только в офисе. Фрилансе тоже не вариант. Вариться в собственном соку, не имея опыта коммандной работы, это путь вникуда. И если , как Вы говорите

> программистских контор мало

то смею предположить, что в этих конторах основной язык программирования это PHP. Имея некоторый опыт программирования на Си, выучить PHP не составит большого труда, я думаю. Я не сторонник PHP, но пока этот язык доминирует в небольших российских городах по числу вакансий. К тому же в среде PHP есть довольно неплохие и востребованные фреймворки: Symfony, Yii например. 
Из того, что вы перечислили, я бы выбрал следующие: C# (без Mono и Unity, Вам хватит, поверьте), JavaScript (при любом раскладе - must know, как говорится).

Answer (score 3):

Под что программировать хотите?

С++ с Qt прекрасно подойдут, т.к. там не только рынок десктопов, но и мобильных осей, а это большие перспективы.

Но в тоже самое JavaScript так же распространён и спрос на фронт-энд разработчиков не малый и постоянно увеличивается. А если учесть ещё и серверные реализации(Node.js) то без хлеба точно не останетесь.

Comment: честно говоря, на Qt и в Москве вакансий не то что бы много, а уж в провинции, думаю, и вовсе по пальцам пересчитать

Comment: Мобильная ось с использованием Qt - это Symbian. Да покоится она с миром!

Answer (score 2):

не нужно думать плохо про Си - он до сих пор востребован. Но не основной массой кодеров, а в нескольких весьма узких сферах, в которых зарплаты очень даже приличные - это микроконтроллеры, т.е. программирование под встроенные системы, ну, и программирование под unix (хотя там все движется в сторону тулкитов типа qt/c++).

Если же хочется писать под десктоп и мобильные платформы - ну, тут уже все сказали: C++/Qt,  C#, Java. Причем тут надо понимать, что по большей части будете изучать не сам язык, а всякие библиотеки, чтобы можно было не изобретать постоянно велосипеды.

И, конечно, же рекомендую определиться именно с направлением - что хотелось бы делать, а не просто болтаться туда-сюда, куда ветер подует.

Answer (score 0):

В наше врямя так или иначе любой мало мальски известный язык кроссплатформенн. Так что если вы хотите кроссплатформенности то выбирать тут можно все что понравиться. Так же обстоит дело и со всеми аспектами программирования, хотим игру - есть готовые движки под любой язык и любую ОС, хотим строить сайт, опять же есть уже готовые решения на любой вкус (а строить странички можно как с использования высокоуровнивых языков так и низкоуровневых), хотим писать приложения с интерфейсом - выбираем что больше понравиться (АПИ системы или какие то сторонние библиотеки), тут как уже ранее говорили нужно не столько изучать сам язык сколько библиотеки для него написанные. И так как все склоняется к изучению библиотек, и перспективности, то выбор будет из 2х языков Java и Python, за плечами первого стоит ОРАКЛ который явно не даст ему умереть, а за вторым громадное сообщество и простота кода. Так же оба языка используются для программирования микроконтроллеров, а на Java даже была написана операционная система, так что они достаточно перспективны, и проектов в которых вы можете принять участие множество!

П.С. Так же программы написанные на этих языках могут быть откомпилированы в байт код, и исполняться не как скрипты а как полноценные бинарные файл.

Хотя я все же посоветовал бы вам Python так как изучить его намного проще, и код программы легко прочитать и понять.

Answer (score 0):

А что конкретно именно Вы, автор, хотите? Какие Ваши предрасположенности? К чему душа больше всего лежит? Мой Вам совет взять бумагу и начать делать такое:

1. Написать список всего что Вам хочется, как будто у Вас времени Вагон
2. Напишите что Вы вообще умеете, даже если Вам что-то не нравится это что-то все таки умение
3. Напишите все умения которые Вам встречаются в Вакансиях
4. Отсортируйте списки

Имея эту информацию Вы сразу же поймете что конкретно надо делать. Проблема людей в том, что они очевидные вещи понимают, но НЕ ДЕЛАЮТ! ;)